# Apple Watch submission failing because of "Missing Icons

Tags: ios, xcode, icons, apple-watch

My submission keeps failing because Xcode says that some times are missing. However, those sizes aren't on the Asset Catalog at all

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AimO2.png

For example, the image says about missing 27.5@2x and 24@2x, but on the catalog:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdnRu.png

There's no such sizes... I just updated Xcode, what am I supposed to do?

Sorry for the links instead of proper images, it says I need 10 reputation to post them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This icons 24pt + 27.5pt must be with 2x scale (48px x 48px and 55px x 55px)

[image]

Comment: This fixed it. Thanks! Really weird of Xcode to say the icon was missing instead of just saying I was using the wrong resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

Are the images actually called "27.5x27.5@2X.png" in example? Might give trouble, not sure, though.

Comment: Nope, the icon files all have the (size)x(size) name format, but none have those names from the errors